# Visual studio command window - one alias for more commands

Tags: visual-studio, command-window

is there a possibility in Visual Studio command window to have one alias for more commands? E.g. one alias for:

- save all
- close all
- show output
- build

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking, no.

I guess you could add your own commands that handle those tasks and then create aliases for them but you might need the Visual Studio SDK for that.